# file not found after clicking comment and it's not recognizing the path of savecomment.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

please see my [pic](http://postimg.org/image/8jvvyarct/) there is my arranged folder,  i'm calling a comment box script into my form using:

```
<?php
    include('comment_script/view/db.php');
    include('comment_script/view/index.php');
    ?>
```

Everything goes fine but i commented into box and after clicking comment, it's showing error `404 Not Found` i guess it's no recognizing the path of `savecomment.php`. so where i'm doing wrong?? help would be appreciated!!

here is my normal form:

```
<body>
<div id="menu_header">

</div>

<div id="posting_status_box"> // here, I'm calling the comment script folder using this......
    <?php
    include('comment_script/view/db.php');
    include('comment_script/view/index.php');
    ?>

</div>

<div id="right_box">
<p style="text-align: center;">Today's Top faces</p>
    <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
```

and here is my `comment_script/view/index.php` code:

(if you wish i could provide full source code...)

```
<?php } ?>
<div class="dddd">
<div>
<img src="profile.jpg" width="32" height="32" />
<form action="savecomment.php" method="post"> // here is an event when i click comment button and it goes here... 
<input name="mesgid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
<input name="mcomment" type="text" placeholder="Write a comment..." style="height: 24px; border:1px solid #BDC7D8; padding:3px; border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px; width:302px;" />
<input id="buts" name="" type="submit" value="ENTER" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my `savecomment.php` code:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$mcomment=$_POST['mcomment'];
$mesgid=$_POST['mesgid'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comments, msg_id_fk)
VALUES ('$mcomment','$mesgid')");
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: sql injection risk there... you appear to be using a framework. What framework is it.

Comment: No, this is not a framework i just downloaded a script from google... and using it ;)

Comment: Can i see whole codes? With exact address.

Comment: @train_fox: Sorry but NO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting to a view, and you appear to be using a framework.

Let us know what framework and perhaps we can provide a more detailed solution.

For now, a generic solution:

1. Create a controller
2. Create a function inside this controller to save the contents of the HTTP POST body
3. Save the contents to the database checking for SQL injection using something built into your framework, like PDO
4. 303 Redirect the user to "/"

In summary: you are not making effective use of this framework, and you are correct in saying that you have the wrong path for your view. Most frameworks have a restriction (using htaccess) that would disallow direct access to that view.